# django store image in database

Tags: django, image, binary, django-blob

Does anyone know if there's an out-of-the box way of storing images directly in the database vs. using ImageField model type that simply uploads it to the MEDIA_ROOT. 
And if there is, how does one serve those images then?

Cheers

Comment: I'd recommend to use the AppEngine Blob Store service. Not exactly  out-of-the-box, but a clean a simple solution. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747730/storing-images-in-db-using-django-models/18778381#18778381

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. And for good reason. It's horribly inefficient to store and serve images from the database. Store them on the filesystem, and serve them directly from Apache.

Comment: perhaps you could give more details on the horrible inefficiencies of storing images in a database?

Comment: It should be noted that serving images using Apache is not recommended.

Comment: @Izzad-DinRuhulessin was that meant as a joke?  If not, citation needed

Comment: Unfounded and wrong. If there's a cache layer after the server, there mightn't be an issue. Storing in database adds portability - a db dump is complete data set.

Comment: Should not be the accepted answer. This depends on the use case and DB.
For example using SQLite to store and retrieve images can even be 35% faster than retrieving from filesystem, see:
https://www.sqlite.org/fasterthanfs.html

Comment: Not really an answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a nice solution here: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1305/ it stores content in a database blob.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no built-in `BlobField` in Django. However, there is one available [here](http://buffis.com/2007/07/25/modifying-django-to-have-a-blobfield-for-storing-binary-data-in-mysql/comment-page-1/). I'm not sure if it supports all backends, but it might work for you. With that, you could write up a form & view that uploades the image as an attachment and stores it as a blob in the database.