# Drop-in custom storage system to store image in a django database

Tags: python, django, django-models

<sub>Before [you tell me its a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771279/django-store-image-in-database), I *know its a bad idea*. I'm not asking if its a good idea, I'm asking how to do it.</sub>

---

I have a requirement to store images from an `ImageField` from a reusable django app into a database, not necessarily the default database, just *a* database.

There is a [python package that does this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-db-file-storage), but it requires altering the original model, which I can't do. Its not being hosted in the Google App Engine, so [a custom solution for that doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18778381/764357).

Ultimately, what I need is to be able to change the [`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE) setting for a Django 1.9 app, and have all images and files from `ImageField` and `FileField` properties be stored into a database.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a custom file storage class and assign it to `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` in order to override the built-in `ImageField` and `FileField` behaviors, as described in the docs: 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-file-storage/

As it has it, there's another project besides the one you mention that's called https://github.com/bfirsh/django-database-files for this same purpose "django-database-files is a storage system for Django that stores uploaded files in the database.", which provides a custom class like the one you would need:

https://github.com/bfirsh/django-database-files/blob/master/database_files/storage.py

This custom file storage class targets Django 1.1, so it may be somewhat dated, but after a quick scan it does appear to implement the methods described in the updated docs [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-file-storage/). If it isn't a drop-in, it should still be helpful as a starting point to implement the class need for database storage.

Comment: Took about 15 minutes of hacking, but this answer still works! Thanks.